# Translate "I will not comply"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Any suggestions on how to translate the phrase "I will not comply?"

I could just translate it word-for-word, but maybe there is something out there in the corpus that's idiomatic.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any idiom. Supposing none exist, you're left with translations such as:

***non oboediam*** (I will not comply)

or

***inoboediam*** (I will disobey).

Comment: I wonder if _nōn pārēbō_ can work too.